# How to remove non-text or back print noises from image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to detect text from in image using pytesseract and openCV. After applying adaptive gaussian threshold i got the following as an output:

[Adaptive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHxGS.jpg)

I also tried OTSU and got the following result :

[OTSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex3rJ.jpg)

My guess is I should use the adaptive image and remove the noises. But I don't know how to remove the noises. Or should i use the OTSU one?

Comment: You would want to filter the small spots, no thresholding. So I would try `medianBlur` and or `morphologyEx` - opening or erosion.

Comment: what you are suggesting is that I shouldn't apply threshold but, use medianBlur or erosion and dilation operation ? or I should apply those on the above thresholded image?

Comment: Looking back, dunno what is the source image, but you might as well start from the thresholded one. The adaptive. Any OCR will have issues in the OTSU result.

Comment: How do i remove the noises from the adaptive one. The source is from a phone camera.

Comment: can you post the source image or some example images?